# Python: way to read data from multiple files into 2D numpy array or list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have `n` number of files and I would like to read data from `m` number of columns from a particular line in each file.  I would like to end up with an `n` by `m` list or array where each line of the list or array is a line from one of the files.  What is a way to do this?  Or is this even the best way to do it?  I could define `m` different lists or arrays (each with a similar name, probably just indexed by numbers) but it seems generally more difficular and complicated to deal with several different lists or arrays than just one list or array with two dimensions.

For instance...

```
file_names = ( "file1" "file2" "file3" "file4" ) # so in this case n is 4
for name in file_names do:
    ###  somehow save the m columns as a row in an array or list
print resulting_list_or_array
```

Some possibly relevant notes:  the `m` columns I want to read from the files are not the first `m` columns in the file (let's say I need to skip `skip_num` columns, and I do actually know what `n` and `m` are.

Also, the row I want to read is not the first row, but rather, say, the `row_num` row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a versatile code using the built-in module `glob` and `numpy.genfromtxt`, as shown in the example below where the second line of many `test*.txt` files will build one 2-D array at the end:

```
from glob import glob

import numpy as np

def read(fname, skip_header=1):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i in range(skip_header):
            f.next()
        return f.next()

a = np.genfromtxt((read(fname) for fname in glob('test*.txt')))
```

Comment: is `glob` a standard module that's usually installed with Python (like, if I run `from glob import glob` in Python on my Linux machine will it most likely work) or will I have to install it myself?

Comment: @Joshua yes... `glob` is a standard module... did you try this answer?

Comment: Not yet.  If I wanted to read a specific line in the file, would I just have to loop over `f.next()` the number of times needed to get to that line?

Comment: @Joshua correct... I've edited the answer to be more general, using the same nomenclature as `numpy.genfromtxt`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems well defined

```
result = []

file_names = ("file1", "file2", "file3", "file4")
for name in file_names do:
    f = open(name)
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 122: # note this will be line_no + 1
            data = line.strip().split()
            result.append([data[0], data[5], data[6], data[9]])

print result # a dynamically created 2D array
```

Comment: What if I want to read a specific row that isn't the first row?  I edited my question above to reflect this.

Comment: That's what `enumerate` and the `if` statement are doing.

Comment: What if `m` is 40?  It seems like, in your line beginning with `result.append` that listing every element specifically will be unwieldy.  Would something like `result.append([data[skip_num:skip_num + m] ])` work?